# Laravel/PHP/MySQL - Best way to store/log data every hour with thousands of users?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am running a platform for showcasing, tracking and managing cryptocurrency investments.
The site is built on the laravel framework and we use MySQL for our databases.

Currently we have over 5800 users in a very short time so we are trying really hard to scale with the immense amount of users we get every day.

What we currently want to do is to have a page where you can see statistics for your portfolio and the first thing we would like to add is the portfolios net worth change past 7 days.

Every portfolio is built with something we call "Investments" all you really need to know about it is that in the database all investments has its own row stating the amount purchased, price when purchased and what currency it is.

Every user has between 1-1000+ investments.

Now we want to start log their net worth (All investments added together) every day or even every hour, but my concern is that looping through all 5800 users and all 80K+ investments in the database and making a new row for each day/hour per user would take to long time or not be efficient.

What would the best way to do this? I was thinking of instead of looping through the database, every time you visited your portfolio it would make a row in the database but then again, if you visit one day and then skip one day, we would miss one day.

I hope I explained this well enough, I would love to hear from you how you would go around solving this.

TLDR: We have 6K~ users and want to log every hour/day what their net worth is using another table which has their investments (About 80K investments).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does looping the DB to fetch the data slows your system? Does it take too much time to gather all information? I´ve ran in similar problems with one of our systems. We have 'fixed' the problem by adding a bookkeeping for each customer via a read-only replica. The question to answer first would be in which interval you want to provide the data to your customers and in which way you want to show it to them.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest storing computer values. It's just bad practice, which yes, may improve performance but I think you might be worrying about nothing at the moment.

1. Ensure you have properly setup your table/s with the right index
   etc.
2. Then ensure you've written your SQL/Eloquent query to be as optimal
   as possible, calculating the Profit/loss per time-increment at DB
   level not code.
3. With that in place loading/calculating the data on each profile view
   shouldn't be that processor hungry. You can cache the result for a
   certain time period if your user base increases which is something
   I'm sure Stack-overflow does.

I write this from experience. I've got a table with 10 Million records over a 7 year time frame. From this data I populate a graph between time-frame based on hit's per time increment. These time-frames are dynamic as are the time increments (Hours/Days/Weeks/Months/Years). Even if I request all 10million records plotted over the entire 7 year period the SQL it's self requires **0.1s** this is the SQL dump to show it's not just some simple query either (Grouped by Date time-span(days)):

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 (1643 total, Query took 0.1214 sec)
SELECT 
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(p0_.timestamp)) AS sclr0,
    count(p0_.timestamp) AS sclr1,
    p0_.id AS id2,
    -- A lot more select-columns here
FROM prod_contacts.cms_actions p0_ 
    LEFT JOIN prod_contacts.cms_contacts p1_ ON p0_.contactid = p1_.id 
    WHERE p1_.clientnumber IS NOT NULL 
    AND p0_.notes LIKE ? 
    AND (p0_.timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?) 
    AND p0_.user IN (?) 
    GROUP BY sclr0 
    ORDER BY p0_.timestamp ASC
```

**Important** : One issue I did have (I use Doctrine not Eloquent) originally hydrating all 10M objects (1 per record) was a complete resource killer and completely unnecessary. Retrieving the results as an array was far-far much more friendly.

## Update to address question in comment:

**Indexing** is probably well covered by Laravel/Eloquent itself but generally you want to ensure an index is present on integer columns and varchar columns by which you intend on querying by `WHERE column = ''` however a waste of an index if the query will be `WHERE column LIKE = '%%'` check here for a starting point on Laravel's schema builder docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema

**Caching**, again is well handled by Laravel, you will want to tweak the settings for your specific needs but here's the docs as a starting point: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache

As far as calculating within the query goes, I generally try to ensure anything that can possibly go into the query does, rather than doing it at application level. Usually (not always) if it’s something SQL **CAN** do, it’ll be faster in SQL than in PHP. Especially calculations of numbers, such as you are intending. A `sum(profit)` with a `GROUP BY (date)` will be near instant and require less loops within PHP trying to get the same result. If you take my example, for example. Your plotting logic will require 1643 loop iterations rather than several million, due to only returning result totals per day rather than ALL results.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for your very detailed answer.
Working in such huge (Not huge but for me its huge!) scales is new for me and I never expected more than 100 to register, so a lot of these things are new for me.
So you suggest that it would be smartest to calculate the profits in the actual query? I actually never thought of that, cause currently now we just pull out all their investments in a query and loop through them calculating the profits 1 by 1, I'll look further into this.
Caching is also something we thought about and lastly, do you know any site I can learn about indexing?

Comment: Datawarehouses do store aggergated values - this is why they are a lot faster in producing reports using aggregation. Disk space is cheaper than processing power.

Comment: Although I agree, I don't think he's at the billions of records level where the effort required would be worth the payoff however. And if he gets to the billions I'm sure he'll have a team working alongside To Help get such a thing running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to start building a data warehouse on top of your transactional data.

Firstly, I do not think that this would have such a large impact performance wise on your db. There is no need to loop, you can use `insert ... select ...` to calculate the hourly summaries and insert them into the hourly stat table. With appropriate multi column indexes on user ids and times, this should not be an issue.The daily stat table should sum up the data in the hourly stat table.

Secondly, if you are still worried about performance, or these stat tables are just the first of many you plan to create, then I would use a different mysql instance (even different server) to house the stats tables. Configure mysql to replicate the transactions to the secondary database and create the stats tables there.

Comment: Hey there thank you for your answer, yes we have planned in the future to use a second server to handle all of the data to not tare on the actual "website server".